# Intercepting field accesses/modifications in C++

Tags: c++, object, process, intercept

Whenever a field of an object is modified or accessed, I would like to intercept it. I want to duplicate the action in another process that will also contain a copy of the same object, and so, need the base address of the object, the field offset, and the value that is set. From this information, I can create a message that tells the other process exactly what to modify. I realize the base pointers will not be the same in the two processes, but that's OK.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Any other suggestions on how to mirror these actions in other processes is welcome, but there need to be other processes - that's part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The this pointer will help you find the address of the object.  The copy constructor will help you contain a copy of the same object.

Comment: Thanks, but how will I be able to intercept modification to the fields?